# Python os.system() with tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, os.system

I want to redirect the output of the os.system() from terminal to Tkinter GUI
Is there any way to achieve this? 
I tried it but its only printing the result on terminal but not on tkinter GUI

Comment: Use subprocess.check_output to capture the output https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/index.html#capturing-output

Comment: thanks for replying 
I want to grab the output of this command 


`output = subprocess.check_output(['java -version'])`

its throwing error

Answer (score 0):

***Yes you can do that but with os.popen. 
  Code:***

```
import os
from Tkinter import *
Outputfileobject=os.popen("your command")
Output=Outputfileobject.read()
Outputfileobject.close()
root=Tk()
root.title("Output text")
Text=Label(root,text=Output).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

> ***Replace "your command" with the command you want to execute***

**os.popen** behaves like a file object.

Answer (score 0):

but `os.popen.read()` returns only when the whole process is completed.if you want to sync the progress and your IO,try this:

```py
def redirect_instant(inobj,outobj,after,*a,**k):
    while True:
        try:
            data = inobj.read(2)
        except EOFError:
            break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.stderr.write("\nError:user interrupted\n")
            after(*a,**k)
        if not data:
            break
        outobj.write(data)
    after(*a,**k)
```

while the **after** function is the function that is executed at the end of the "copy stream" process or at CTRL-C KeyboardInterrupt exception

`inobj.read(2)` indicates that everytime the process outputs 2 bytes it is copied to **outobj** instead of copying after all output is produced.